# Audio file php pop up on selection

Tags: php, html, audio

I have a poetry site where I currently use a link to `.swf` audio files, a person can click to hear the poem and read in the authors voice.

Problem is certain browsers do not natively include Flash player. I want to use HTML5's `<audio>` tags to provide mp3 or ogg audio files, but I do not want them embedded so pages load faster.

Is there a way to do this with links and PHP to show a popup with nothing but the control and window close button? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,
Rusty Rimes

Comment: This isn't something you can do with php alone.  You should be using a client side library like jQuery.

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery, you can just echo the url of your audio file into a link and add `target='_blank'` to the hyperlink: `echo "<a href=\"$url\" target=\"_blank\">My Audio File</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="http://www.poems.com/path/to/Shakesphere.mp3" target="_blank">McBeth</a>
```